# Play Last recording in Watchkit OS 2

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, watchkit, nsurl, nsbundle

i use the sample codes from apple for recording and playing the last recording 
but i can't play the last recording

here are the codes

```
- (IBAction)playLastRecording {

    // Present the media player controller for the last recorded URL.
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              WKMediaPlayerControllerOptionsAutoplayKey : @YES
                              };

    [self presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:self.lastRecordingURL options:options completion:^(BOOL didPlayToEnd, NSTimeInterval endTime, NSError * __nullable error) {
        if (!didPlayToEnd) {
            NSLog(@"The player did not play all the way to the end. The player only played until time - %.2f.", endTime);
        }

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"There was an error with playback: %@.", error);
        }
    }];



}
```

and here is the error

i think we need to use the NSbundle and nsurl connection but how

to use for **self.lastRecordingURL**

please writing the correct codes for this problems

**Optional(Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=4 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (1), NSUnderlyingError=0x17d9bf50 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed})**

Comment: Did you fixed this issue?

Comment: No if you have a solution please share it here @Vishnu Kumar. S

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Make sure that the audio data is saved to the Apps Group correctly with the correct extension of the file.

If you are trying to record the audio file use the following codes.

```
- (void)startRecording
{
    // Creating a path for saving the recorded audio file.
    // We have to write the files to the shared group folder, as this is the only place both the app and extension can see.
    NSURL *container = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:APP_GROUP_IDENTIFIER];

    NSURL *outputURL = [container URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"AudioFile.m4a"];
    // Setting the recorder options.
    NSDictionary *dictMaxAudioRec = @{@"WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsMaximumDurationKey":MAX_REC_DURATION};
    // Presenting the default audio recorder.
    [self presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL:outputURL preset:WKAudioRecorderPresetWideBandSpeech options:dictMaxAudioRec completion:^(BOOL didSave, NSError * error) {
        if(didSave)
        {
            // Successfully saved the file.
            NSURL *extensionDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].firstObject;
            NSUInteger timeAtRecording = (NSUInteger)[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
            NSString *dirName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AudioFile%d/",timeAtRecording];
            NSURL *outputExtensionURL = [extensionDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:dirName];

            // Move the file to new directory.
            NSError *moveError;
            BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:outputURL toURL:outputExtensionURL error:&moveError];

            if (!success) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to move the outputURL to the extension's documents direcotry: %@", moveError);
            }
            else {
                NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:outputExtensionURL];
                NSLog(@"Actual Audio Data length: %lu", (unsigned long)audioData.length);
                if(audioData.length)
                {
                    // We have a valid audio data,do what ever you want to do with this data 
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Something went wrong.
            NSLog(@"%s - %@",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Or if you are trying to play a video that you have downloaded from other source or passed from the paired phone, write the audio data first to the App Groups with file extension. The following codes may help you for that.

```
- (void)writeAudioToAppGroupsWithData:(NSData *)audioData
{
    // Writing the audio data to the App Groups
    NSURL *containerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:APP_GROUP_IDENTIFIER];
    containerURL = [containerURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:DIRECTORY_PATH]];
    [audioData writeToURL:containerURL atomically:YES];
}
```

In this case make sure that your **DIRECTORY_PATH** is **Library/Caches/filename.extension**. 
Eg: Library/Caches/Audio.mp3

For playing the saved audio use the following codes.

```
- (void)playAudio
{
    // Playing the audio from the url using the default controller
    [self presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:[self getAudioUrl] options:nil completion:^(BOOL didPlayToEnd, NSTimeInterval endTime, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);
    }];
}
```

You can get the audio url from the App Groups.

```
- (NSURL *)getAudioUrl
{
    // Getting the audio url from the App Groups
    NSURL *container = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:APP_GROUP_IDENTIFIER];
    NSURL *outputURL = [container URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:DIRECTORY_PATH]];
    return outputURL;
}
```

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for answer one question for last part in (Audio Get)
how can i  get  DIRECTORY_PATH

Comment: You can define it as @"Library/Caches/Audio.mp3"

Comment: i receiving the error 
Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=4 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x145b9d20 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server.}
@Vishnu Kumar. S